# Spring Boot Fire and Forget Rest Calls

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am looking for a possibility to make non-blocking rest calls from a thread in spring boot like "fire-and-forget".

I somehow expected to be able to just configure RestTemplate to execute requests without waiting for the response, but apparently it's not that easy.

Of course I have found @Async asking Google. But the problem in my case is, that sometimes at the end of my rest-api-call-chain (app1 -> app2 -> app3 -> return to app2 -> return to app1), something can fail without a direct exception. (I know this is also a problem.) But so the thread in the first position is waiting and waiting and never dies and just blocks following requests. And this I want to avoid by sending requests from app1 to app2 without waiting for a response, to not block the thread pool.

Is there another possibility than @Async? Or any other ways I am missing?

Comment: this basically looks like a design question: in a distributed environment, you can call a REST API and API shall return with 200 OK or basic validation failed messages 
then underneath code can 
PATCH the update to a REST endpoint or 
write to KAFKA topic 
depends on your architecture and use case

Comment: Use @Async to fire and return immediately.  You'll have to decide on a strategy for dealing with exceptions.  For example, 1) try again; 2) trigger an alert for a human to deal with; 3) invoke a callback and let app1 deal with it; 4) not critical so ignore the exception; 5) ...

Comment: @AndrewS But a rest call in a thread started from "@Async" is also waiting for a response, isn't it? Isn't there a way to really fire and forget a rest call?

Comment: @Async will run on a different thread, which allows the original rest call to return immediately. The response could just be an http OK indicating the call was successful (which is unrelated to the eventual result of the method running in some other thread).

Comment: @AndrewS I understand thank you for explanation. But what I mean is, that the (async) method running in some other thread would wait then for a response of a rest call (instead of the original), right?

Comment: not sure what you mean, but app1 -> app2.  where app2 has an async method so some response (such as just an HTTP OK with no body) is sent immediately back to app1.  Meanwhile (in the other thread), app2 -> app3, and eventually app3 returns a response to app2.